# How can I make Unity search not remember my previous search term?

Tags: 15.10, unity-dash

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Press Meta key
2. Type a search term
3. Press Meta key again
4. Press Meta key again

I don't want Unity to remember the search term of step 2 at step 4. **However**, I do want Unity to remember my recent files.

Can I disable this behaviour?

**More resources:**

- Screencast: https://vid.me/oc1q

Comment: That's how it was designed, however the search is highlighted so removed if you type anything (or hit backspace key

Comment: Dear @doug, I appreciate your comment. It seems indeed that this was a design decision. I don't want to lose my remembered files as suggested below. Thus, I will train myself to use the backspace key.